# Drupal7 - Creating Ads

Tags: drupal-7

I'm recreating a website in drupal7 from a basic html page. This basic current html page has these two sidebars with specify ads squares for their website that they have made. This website is really old so all of their ad squares are created in images. So there is bassicly just an img tag in one ofthese squares. In these pictures there is also an link to donation pages and other functions etc. It's done with an easy a tag. Anyway...

I want to create these ads squares in the sidebars for their new drupal site but I have no idea of how to do it. I've looked into CKEdtior and CKFinder but I dont find functions for it. I want to recreate these pictures into real divs that has css styling.

Do you guys have any idea of how to create these ads square to the new drupal site? :)

Modueles?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the ad as a **block**. Blocks can be displayed in certain regions of your theme, on all or on certain pages of your site.

See [Working with blocks (content in regions)](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/block).

---

EDIT:

If your users shall be able to create new ads, you could do the following:

- create a content type "Ad"
- add all the fields you need, set the permissions
- with the [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) module, you can create a new block display, which contains the relevant fields of your "Ad" content type

What else you have to do depends on when/how/which ads shall be displayed.

Comment: Yes that would work but I want the user to also add an peice of ad block with the help of a content type. Do you see my point? sorry for my english hehe

Comment: @user2945872: I see. You should specify that in your question. I updated my answer.

Comment: Right, but I forgot to mention that I want to remake these pictures into pure CSS styling. Will that be a problem to this?

Comment: @user2945872: Rewrite the markup with inline `style` attributes, or, for more complex cases, custom View templates should do the trick. The specific implementation of the ad markup/styling is a different question, though.